# Firebase route still continuing after error status

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

So I've been watching tutorials about Firebase and I'm creating a simple twitter like app.

With schema of `screams` and `comments`

In my createScreamComment my problem is that after I validate that there's no `scream` document the route will send a **404** status which it did. But it keeps hitting other return as well which is triggering my `catch error` because of `[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

**exports.commentOnScream**

```
exports.commentOnScream = (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.body.trim() === '')
        return res.status(400).json({ comment: 'Must not be empty' });

    const newComment = {
        body: req.body.body,
        createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
        screamId: req.params.screamId,
        userHandle: req.user.handle,
        userImage: req.user.imageUrl
    };

    db.doc(`/screams/${req.params.screamId}`)
        .get()
        .then((doc) => {
            if (!doc.exists) { // triggering success stop here
                return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Scream not found' });
            } else {
                return doc.ref.update({ commentCount: doc.data().commentCount + 1 });
            }
        })
        .then(() => { // dont know why this is getting triggered already sent a 404 response
            return db.collection('comments').add(newComment);
        })
        .then(() => { // dont know why this is getting triggered already sent a 404 response
            return res.json(newComment);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Something went wrong' });
        });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your `then` callbacks are going to get invoked in the order that they're chained from each other.  That behavior is normal, and just the way that promise chains work.  Sending a response via Express is not going to terminate the chain.

You might want to consider moving the logic that should only happen when a document is found into the appropriate conditional block.  For example, briefly:

```
.then(doc => {
    if (!doc.exists) {
        res.status(404).json({ error: 'Scream not found' });
    }
    else {
        return doc.ref.update(...)
        .then(() => {
            return db.collection('comments').add(newComment);
        })
        .then(() => {
            res.json(newComment);
        })
    }
})
```

Alternatively, these sorts of things get easier if you adopt async/await syntax so you don't end up with so many nested callbacks.